# не работает метод jquery

Tags: jquery

Можете объяснить, почему при нажатии на одну из 4 конопок, кнопки в появляющихся дивах не реагирует на методы jquery. Когда я нажимаю на одну из 4 кнопок, все хорошо обрабатывается, но когда я пробую нажимать на вновь появившиеяся кнопки ничего не происходит(P.S. сорри за корявый код, в css 2 раза объявлял свойства для класса task)

```css
* {
vertical-align: baseline;
font-weight: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
outline: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}/*Отмена стилей браузера*/
body{
 height: 10000px;
}/*длина сайта(страницы)*/
textarea{
 color:black;
 border:1px solid red;
}/*настройка всех текстовых полей*/
.main_text{
 margin-top: 20px; 
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.task{
 top: 5px;
 position: relative;
 border:1px solid orange;
 width: 95%;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*Настройка поля с Основным заданием*/
 .testtext1{
 
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;

 
 
}/* поле С Заданием 1*/

.first{
 margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.icontest{
 float: left;
 width: 240px;
 height:auto;
 
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;

 
}/*Поле для всавляемого изображения*/
 #inputfile{
 
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
}/* Кнопка для добавления файлов*/

#areatext{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}/* Настройка поля для ввода от задания 1*/
.input_text{
 margin-top: 30px;
 
}

.button{
 
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 155px;
 padding-bottom: 158px;
 padding-left: 105px;
 padding-right: 105px;
 background-color: #ffd694;
 font-size: 50px;
 color:#ff4d00;
 border: 2px dashed orange;
 
}/* Настройка Кнопки ДОБАВИТЬ*/
.button:hover{
 transition: all .5s;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}/* Анимация Кнопки ДОБАВИТЬ*/
.add{
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#radio{
 
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 
}/* Настройка радио кнопок*/
.button_radio
{
 margin-top: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}


#check{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
}/* Настройка чек боксов*/
.button_checkbox{
 margin-top: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;

}

#inp{
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}/* Настройка поля для ввода от задания 3*/
#inp input{
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 240px;
}/* Настройка поля для ввода от задания 3*/





.add_button_answer{

 position: relative;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 padding-left: 109px;
 padding-right: 109px;
 background-color: #ffd694;
 font-size: 30px;
 color:#ff4d00;
 border: 2px dashed orange;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.add_button_answer:hover{
 transition: all .5s;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}/* Анимация Кнопки ДОБАВИТЬ*/


#footer{display: none;

 margin-top: 10000px;
}/* футер*/

.task{
 display:none;
}
* {
vertical-align: baseline;
font-weight: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
outline: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body{
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu_bg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 61px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 360px;
 margin:0 auto; 
 opacity: 1;
 
 
}
#menu_bg:hover{
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.text_mainbg{
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 200px;
 margin-left: 40%;
 margin-right: 40%;
 background-color:black;
 border-radius: 10%;
 padding: 2px;
}
#menu_bg #logo{
 margin-top: 90px;
 margin-left: 45%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: black;
}

#nav_menu{
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 border:1px solid red;
 background-color: orange
 
}

#main_content{
 position: absolute;
 top: 510px;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 15%;
 width: 70%;
 height: 700px;
 border: 1px solid red;

}

#menu1 ul li{
 padding: 20px;
 /*margin-right: 20px;*/

}
#menu1 ul li, #menu1 ul{
 display: inline-block;
}
#menu1 ul{
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 /*background-color: orange;*/

}

#menu1 ul ul{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: white;

}
#menu1 ul > li:hover{
 background-color: darkorange;
}
#menu1 ul  a{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#menu1 ul ul a{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;

}
#menu1 li:hover ul{
 display: block;
 top: 60px;
 margin-left: -20px;
    }
#menu1 li:hover li{
 display: block;
}
#menu1 ul li a{
 font-size: 18px;
}
#menu1 ul li ul li{
 margin: 0;
}
#nav_menu .profile{
 text-align: right;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;



 
}
#nav_menu .profile a{
 font-size: 19px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:  black;
 padding:20px;
}
#nav_menu .profile a:hover{
 background-color: darkorange;
 background-size: 
}

#footer{
 top: 1200px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: black;
 bottom: 0;
 
}
#footer .text {
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 top: 40px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#right_block{
 top:550px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 0.5%;
 width: 14%;
 height: 600px;
 border:1px solid red;
}

#left_block{
 top:550px;
 margin-left: 85.5%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-right: 0.5%;
 width: 14%;
 height: 600px;
 border:1px solid red;
}

#plus_inform{
 position: absolute;
 top: 450px;
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 background-color: orange;
}
.slider{
 position: absolute;
 top: 70px;
 width: 99.2%;
 height: 360px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 5px solid orange;
}
.navigation{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 16px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 display: flex;
}
.bar{
 height: 8px;
 width: 30px;
 margin: 6px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: red;
 opacity: 0.7;
 border-radius: 10px;
 transition: all .4s ease;
}
.bar:hover{
 opacity: 0.9;
 transform: scale(2);
}
input[name='r']{
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.slides{
 width: 400%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
}
.slide{
 width: 25%;
 transition: all .6s ease;
}
.slide img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#r1:checked ~ .s1{
 margin-left: 0;
}
#r2:checked ~ .s1{
 margin-left: -25%;
}

#r3:checked ~ .s1{
 margin-left: -50%;
}

#r4:checked ~ .s1{
 margin-left: -75%;
}
#menu1 ul li {
 border-right: 2px solid red;
 padding-left: 20px;
 

}
#menu1 ul li a{
 margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/Register.css?123" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/cssfortest.css?123" type="text/css">
 <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#form_1').click(function(){
    $('.textarea_template:hidden').clone().insertBefore('#form_handler').slideDown(1000);
   });
   $('#form_2').click(function(){
    $('.radiobutton_template:hidden').clone().insertBefore('#form_handler').slideDown(1000);
   });
   $('#form_3').click(function(){
    $('.checkboxbutton_template:hidden').clone().insertBefore('#form_handler').slideDown(1000);
   });
   $('#form_4').click(function(){
    $('.input_template:hidden').clone().insertBefore('#form_handler').slideDown(1000);
   });
   $('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp(1000);
   });
  });
  
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div id="page">
  
  <div id="main_content"><!--  Основной див  сайта -->
   <form action="">
   <div id="form_handler">
   <input type="button" value="1 форма" id="form_1">
   <input type="button" value="2 форма" id="form_2">
   <input type="button" value="3 форма" id="form_3">
   <input type="button" value="4 форма" id="form_4">
   </div>
<div class="task textarea_template">
      
  <textarea class="main_text" cols="110" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder=""> 
  </textarea><!-- Общее задание -->
       
  <div class="icontest">
   <img id="uploadPreview" style="width:240px; height: 240px;" />
    <input id="inputfile" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" accept="image/*" /><!-- Вставить изображение -->
    <textarea class="testtext1 first" id="text" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder="">
    </textarea><!--  задание1 -->
  </div>
        
  <input type="button" class="button" value="+"><!--  Кнопка добавить -->
        
  <div id="areatext">
   <textarea name="" id="" cols="110" rows="3" style="resize:none">
   </textarea><!--  Развернутый ответ -->
  </div>
      
 </div>
 <div class="task radiobutton_template">
  <textarea class="main_text" cols="110" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder=""> 
  </textarea><!-- Общее задание -->
  <div class="icontest ">
   <img id="uploadPreview" style="width:240px; height: 240px;" />
   <input id="inputfile" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" accept="image/*" /><!-- Вставить изображение -->
   <textarea class="testtext1" id="text" name="" id="" cols="32" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder="">
   </textarea><!--  задание1 -->
  </div>
      
  <input type="button" class="button add" value="+"><!--  Кнопка добавить -->
      
  <div id="radio">
   <input name="" type="radio" value="" class="button_radio">  <!--  радио кнопка -->
   <textarea class="input_text" id="text" name="" id="" cols="28" rows="1" style="resize:none" placeholder="">
   </textarea><!--  задание1 -->
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="add_button_answer" value="+"><!--  Кнопка добавить -->
      
 </div>
 <div class="task checkboxbutton_template">
  <textarea class="main_text" cols="110" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder=""> 
  </textarea><!-- Общее задание -->
  <div class="icontest">
   <img id="uploadPreview" style="width:240px; height: 240px;" />
   <input id="inputfile" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" accept="image/*" /><!-- Вставить изображение -->
   <textarea class="testtext1" id="text" name="" id="" cols="32" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder="">
   </textarea><!--  задание1 -->  
  </div>
      
  <input type="button" class="button add" value="+"><!--  Кнопка добавить -->
      
  <div id="check">
   <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="" class="button_checkbox" > <!--  чекбокс -->

   <textarea class="input_text" id="text" name="" id="" cols="28" rows="1" style="resize:none" placeholder="">
   </textarea><!--  задание1 -->
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="add_button_answer" value="+"><!--  Кнопка добавить -->
 </div>
 <div class="task input_template">
  <textarea class="main_text" cols="110" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder=""> 
  </textarea><!-- Общее задание -->
  <div class="icontest">
   <img id="uploadPreview" style="width:240px; height: 240px;" />
   <input id="inputfile" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" accept="image/*" /><!-- Вставить изображение -->
   <textarea class="testtext1" id="text" name="" id="" cols="32" rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder="поздровляю">
   </textarea><!--  задание1 -->
  </div>
      
  <input type="button" class="button add" value="+"><!--  Кнопка добавить -->
  <div id="inp">
   <input type="text" name="a" value=""> <!--  Поле для ввода ответа -->
  </div>
      
 </div>
  </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">

        function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("inputfile").files[0]);

            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
            };
        };

    </script><!--  Превью Изображения на сайте -->
   
   </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: Я не понял куда когда надо нажимать. Попробуйте уменьшить Ваш пример раз в десять.

Comment: @Максим Ларченко Нажатие каких кнопок у Вас не работает?

Comment: Нажмите теперь на одну из четырех кнопок, затем на появившуюся кнопку с плюсом, именно кнопки с плюсом не реагирую на события

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение, просто плохо понимал, как работает clone(), у меня просто не работал обработчик событий для дочерних элементов. Нашел, что достаточно в параметры этой функции передать deepWithDataAndEvents